# Social Sciences or social sciences or Social Science or social science

Tags: difference

How should we write the names of academic subjects?

For instance, I know that "math" has to be written with a capital letter:

- Math

What about "social sciences"? What do we have to write:

- I study ***S***ocial ***S***cience***s***
- I study *S*ocial *S*cience
- I study social science*s*
- I study social science

Answer (score 1):

Normally we DON'T capitalize "math" in general usage. Like if I said, "My favorite subject in high school was math", I wouldn't capitalize it.

And so similarly for "social sciences". If you're just talking about the subject in general, don't capitalize.

If you're talking about the name of a department or an organization, then it becomes part of a proper name and should be capitalized. Like, "I am pleased to announce that Dr Jones has joined the Social Sciences Department", or "A press release from the National Association of Social Science Professionals (NASSP) says that ..."

I'm speaking as an American. Perhaps the usage is different in some other English-speaking country? (But you said "math" and not "maths", so I'm guessing you're not talking about the UK.)

*Update*

Oh, I skipped over the part about "social science" versus "social sciences".

Any given subject could be a "social science". If you have several of them, then it's plural, "social sciences". Like, "Psychology is a social science." Or, "Psychology and sociology are social sciences." It's the same as any other general term. Like consider "animal". "A dog is an animal. Cats and dogs are animals." Etc.

Comment: Thank you for you answer! It would be great, if some of the British people also shared their opinion on the matter

Comment: British usage is the same. I had to look up whether  it should be singular or plural, but Wikipedia redirects you from _social sciences_ to _social science_.

Comment: Thank you a lot, Jay and Kate! Somebody does downvote my posts all the time and, probably, your answer was downvoted too by this person... Thank you again, guys!